# Is PHP 7.2 compatible with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, php

The [PHP Manual section on installation requirements](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php) says "As of PHP 7.2.0 Windows 2008 and 7 are no longer supported."

The [section on compatibility of version 7.2](http://php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php) says, near the bottom under *Windows Support* "The officially supported, minimum Windows versions are now Windows 7/Server 2008 R2."

The [PHP downloads page for Windows](https://windows.php.net/download/) offers some advice on which version to get for different configurations, but it doesn't say anything about any particular version of Windows.

These first two statements are contradictory. Is Windows supported for PHP 7.2 or not?

I wanted to ask this question on one of the [PHP mailing lists](http://php.net/mailing-lists.php), but when I attempted to subscribe to some, I did not get the necessary confirming e-mail. (I checked that the e-mail address I entered was correct and there's nothing from PHP in my junk folder.)

I need to install PHP on my Windows 7 machine. If the warning on the installation requirements page is correct, then I should get version 7.1. But if the 7.2 compatibility page is right, then I should be safe with that version. Does someone here know which one is correct?

Comment: This question is within scope here at Superuser.  This question should NOT be migrated to StackOverflow.  Even if this was migrated migration will be rejected when it's closed at StackOverflow.

Comment: @Ramhound - Is there a reason you thought someone might think it's out-of-scope and send it over to StackOverflow?

Comment: There are 2 votes to migrate this question to StackOverflow...If my comment isn’t appreciated....I will delete it

Comment: No, that's fine, I was just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is PHP 7.2 compatible with Windows 7

It absolutely is compatible with Windows 7

[image]

> Version 7.2.0 - 30 Nov 2017
>
> - Core
>
>   - Raised minimum supported Windows versions to Windows 7/Server 2008 R2.

[Source](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.7)

The changelog indicates that PHP 7.2.X supports **Windows 7** and **Windows Server 2008 R2**

> As of PHP 7.2.0 Windows 2008 and 7 are no longer supported. 
>   [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php)

**This statement is obviously incorrect.**  **Windows Server 2008** is based on **Windows Vista** not **Windows 7**.  PHP 7.2.0 based on the changelog no longer supports **Windows Vista**.  The PHP Manual is created by the community, and it allows anonymous editors to make changes to it, and it clearly is incorrect.

Only the [PHP 7 Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.2.7) was written by the PHP Developers.